# JPA QL for not in condition

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a one to one relationship of `Employee` and `ParkingSpace` entities with parkingId set as `@OneToOne` and optional on employee and `mappedBy` set in ParkingSpace entity.

`ParkingSpace` is not mandatory for `Employee` and when it is allocated, `parkingId` will be set

Now i wanted to write a JPA QL to find out list of parking spaces that are not yet allocated.

I started with

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PARKING_SPACE")
@NamedQueries

({
@NamedQuery(name="ParkingSpace.findAllavailableInLocation",

query="select p from ParkingSpace p where p.emp IS NULL and p.location = :location")

})

public class ParkingSpace {

    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PARKING_ID_GENERATOR", 

            sequenceName = "PARKING_SEQ" ,initialValue=10 ,allocationSize=1)
    @Id

    @GeneratedValue(generator = "PARKING_ID_GENERATOR")

    private int id;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy="parking")

    private Employee emp;
```

But hibernate 4.3 is generating query as

```
19:29:58.654 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL -

select parkingspa0_.id as id1_3_, parkingspa0_.location as location2_3_, parkingspa0_.lot as lot3_3_ 

from PARKING_SPACE parkingspa0_ where 
(parkingspa0_.id is null) and parkingspa0_.location=?
```

it is ignoring the emp field in ParkingSpace object and going for id field.

i tried with p.emp.id is null in the JPA QL and it generates as

```
select parkingspa0_.id as id1_3_, parkingspa0_.location as location2_3_,
 parkingspa0_.lot as lot3_3_
 from PARKING_SPACE parkingspa0_ cross join Employee employee1_
 where parkingspa0_.id=employee1_.PSPACE_ID and (employee1_.id is null) and parkingspa0_.location=?
```

while what i wanted was

```
select * from parking_space where id not in (select pspace_id from employee);
```

I can understand the second one that as i asked for `p.emp.id` is null it generated the condition i wanted. but it will not solve the problem and always no rows will be returned
as there will be no employees without id as its the PKEY

What am i missing here? i just wanted parking spaces that are not allocated to employees.

Answer (score 0):

The jpql should be:

```
select p from ParkingSpace p
  where p.emp.pspace_id not in :pspace_id

// pspace_id should be the mapped field of the Employee class
```

While creating named query from EntityManager, it will be something like below.

```
List<Long> pspaceIdList; // has some value
return em.createNamedQuery("ParkingSpace.findAllavailableInLocation")
  .setParameter("pspace_id", pspaceIdList)
  .getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

i got this working by below JPA QL.

select p from ParkingSpace p where p.id NOT IN (select e.parking.id from Employee e)

eclipse link was atleast going in the right direction to consider employee also in the query. but hibernate completely missed it :-)

Vam